# Why this definition of vector of shared_ptr can pass the compiler checking?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost

I have seen the following definition throughout legacy code:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<ClassNameAAA>> vecClass;
```

I am able to compile it with VS2008 w/o problems.

**Question**> My understanding is that the following line should be used instead:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<ClassNameAAA> > vecClass;

                                           ^ Add a space here
```

Am i correct on this? If any, why VS2008 allows this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those several MS extensions.

> Am i correct on this?

Yes your understanding is correct. `>>` would be parsed as right shift operator.

However C++11 supports [right-angle brackets](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#brackets).

---

Answer (score 1):

MSVC++ 2008 is able to parse this because of a language extension.

Many compilers have extensions for features that eventually become part of the language.  Being able to parse nested template declarations without the space is now required in the new C++11 standard.